# Serving error page to portlet resource response when pdf generation fails

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, pdf-generation, portlet

I've got a resource aware spring mvc portlet that I'm using to serve a PDF. Previously our method for serving PDFs from a portlet has been to link to a servlet to actually write the PDF response. Our pattern in the servlets was basically this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream certIn = null;
        try {
            certIn = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
            if (certIn.available() > 0) {
                while (certIn.available() > 0) {
                    out.write(certIn.read());
                }
                out.flush();
            }                       
        } catch (IOException e) {
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp").include(request, response);
        } finally {
            if (certIn != null) {
                try {
                    certIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOG.warn(
                            "Failed to close FileInputStream", e);
                }
            }
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOG.warn("Failed to close ServletOutputStream", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm now trying to replicate this in the resource aware portlet. The problem I've got is if we get an error, I can't get it to redirect to the error jsp.

If I use the portletContext.getRequestDispatcher() to forward to a jsp, I get an error saying I can't call getWriter() after getOuputStream(). I get the same error if I try to return a spring ModelAndView to the error.jsp.

Can anyone suggest how I can redirect the user to a jsp after calling getOutputStream() on the ResourceResponse?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure about Portlets, but the way I have done this in normal non-Portlet is to have my request handler return ModelAndView.  When the file generation succeeds, I set the "view" to a custom view that extends org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView that simply writes out our payload to the response objects OutputStream (similar to how you are doing it above).  If it fails, we set the view using the standard ViewResolver we normally use, which in our case is the JspViewResolver (I think this is the name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the order of what I was doing slightly in the end. Now don't call getPortletOutputStream() until I know the file exists and is readable. If it fails whilst actually writing to the output stream it cannot serve the jsp, but that's the case for the servlet too.